# Want to store variable names in list, not said variable's contents

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nltk, text-classification

Sorry if the title is confusing; let me explain.

So, I've written a program that categorizes emails by topic using nltk and tools from sklearn.

Here is that code:

```
#Extract Emails
tech = extract_message("C:\\Users\\Cody\\Documents\\Emails\\tech.html")
gary = extract_message("C:\\Users\\Cody\\Documents\\Emails\\gary.html")
gary2 = extract_message("C:\\Users\\Cody\\Documents\\Emails\\gary2.html")
jesus = extract_message("C:\\Users\\Cody\\Documents\\Emails\\Jesus.html")
jesus2 = extract_message("C:\\Users\\Cody\\Documents\\Emails\\jesus2.html")
hockey = extract_message("C:\\Users\\Cody\\Documents\\Emails\\hockey.html")
hockey2 = extract_message("C:\\Users\\Cody\\Documents\\Emails\\hockey2.html")
shop = extract_message("C:\\Users\\Cody\\Documents\\Emails\\shop.html")

#Build dictionary of features
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
x_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(news.data)

#Downscaling
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
x_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(x_train_counts)
tf_transformer = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False).fit(x_train_counts)
x_train_tf = tf_transformer.transform(x_train_counts)

#Train classifier
clf = MultinomialNB().fit(x_train_tfidf, news.target)

#List of the extracted emails
docs_new = [gary, gary2, jesus, jesus2, shop, tech, hockey, hockey2]

#Extract feautures from emails
x_new_counts = count_vect.transform(docs_new)
x_new_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(x_new_counts)

#Predict the categories for each email
predicted = clf.predict(x_new_tfidf)
```

Now I'm looking to store each variable in an appropriate list, based off of the predicted label. I figured I could do that doing this:

```
#Store Files in a category
hockey_emails = []
computer_emails = []
politics_emails = []
tech_emails = []
religion_emails = []
forsale_emails = []

#Print out results and store each email in the appropritate category list
for doc, category in zip(docs_new, predicted):
  print('%r ---> %s' % (doc, news.target_names[category]))
   if(news.target_names[category] == 'comp.sys.ibm.pc.hardware'):
        computer_emails.append(doc)
   if(news.target_names[category] == 'rec.sport.hockey'):
        hockey_emails.append(doc)
   if(news.target_names[category] == 'talk.politics.misc'):
       politics_emails.append(doc)
   if(news.target_names[category] == 'soc.religion.christian'):
       religion_emails.append(doc)
   if(news.target_names[category] == 'misc.forsale'):
       forsale_emails.append(doc)
   if(news.target_names[category] == 'comp.sys.ibm.pc.hardware'):
       computer_emails.append(doc)
```

My output if I were to print out one of these lists, let's say hockey for instance, displays the contents stored in the variable rather than the variable itself.

I want this:

```
print(hockey_emails)

output: ['hockey', 'hockey2']
```

but instead I'm getting this:

```
 output: ['View View online click here Hi Thanks for signing up as a EA SPORTS NHL insider You ll now receive all of the latest and greatest news and info at this e mail address as you ve requested EA com If you need technical assistance please contact EA Help Privacy Policy Our Certified Online Privacy Policy gives you confidence whenever you play EA games To view our complete Privacy and Cookie Policy go to privacy ea com or write to Privacy Policy Administrator Electronic Arts Inc Redwood Shores Parkway Redwood City CA Electronic Arts Inc All Rights Reserved Privacy Policy User Agreement Legal ActionsMark as UnreadMark as ReadMark as SpamStarClear StarArchive Previous Next ', 'View News From The Hockey Writers The Editor s Choice stories from The Hockey Writers View this email in your browser edition Recap Stars Steamroll Predators By Matt Pryor on Dec am As the old Mary Chapin Carpenter song goes Sometimes you re the windshield Sometimes you re the bug It hasn t happened very often this season but the Dallas Stars had a windshield Continue Reading A Review of Years in Blue and White Damien Cox One on One By Anthony Fusco on Dec pm The Toronto Maple Leafs are one of the most storied and iconic franchises in the entire National Hockey League They have a century of history that spans all the way back to the early s When you have an Continue Reading Bruins Will Not Miss Beleskey By Kyle Benson on Dec am On Monday it was announced that Matt Beleskey will miss the next six weeks due to a knee injury he sustained over the weekend in a game against the Buffalo Sabres Six weeks is a long stint to be without a potential top Continue Reading Recent Articles Galchenyuk Injury Costly for CanadiensFacing Off Picking Team Canada for World JuniorsAre Johnson s Nomadic Days Over Share Tweet Forward Latest News Prospects Anaheim Ducks Arizona Coyotes Boston Bruins Buffalo Sabres Calgary Flames Carolina Hurricanes Chicago Blackhawks Colorado Avalanche Columbus Blue Jackets Dallas Stars Detroit Red Wings Edmonton Oilers Florida Panthers Los Angeles Kings Minnesota Wild Montreal Canadiens Nashville Predators New Jersey Devils New York Islanders New York Rangers Philadelphia Flyers Pittsburgh Penguins Ottawa Senators San Jose Sharks St Louis Blues Tampa Bay Lightning Toronto Maple Leafs Vancouver Canucks Washington Capitals Winnipeg Jets Copyright The Hockey Writers All rights reserved You are receiving this email because you opted in at The Hockey Writers or one of our Network Sites Our mailing address is The Hockey Writers Victoria Ave St Lambert QC J R R CanadaAdd us to your address book unsubscribe from this list update subscription preferences ActionsMark as UnreadMark as ReadMark as SpamStarClear StarArchive Previous Next ']
```

I figured this would be simple, but I'm sitting here scratching my head. Is this even possible? Should I use something else instead of a list? This is probably simple I'm just blanking.

Comment: You have no variable called `hockey` or `hockey2`, so presumably these are values in a different variable - store that instead.

Comment: in which variable do you have text `hockey`  and `hockey2` ? in `category` ? then `append(category)` instead of `append(doc)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep track of the names yourself, Python won't do it for you.

```
names = 'gary gary2 Jesus jesus2 shop tech hockey hockey2'.split()
docs_new = [extract_message("C:\\Users\\Cody\\Documents\\Emails\\%s.html" % name)
            for name in names]

for name, category in zip(names, predicted):
    print('%r ---> %s' % (name, news.target_names[category]))
    if (news.target_names[category] == 'comp.sys.ibm.pc.hardware'):
        computer_emails.append(name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this. Use a dictionary to hold your collection of emails, and you can print the dictionary keys when you want to know what is what.

```
docs_new = dict()
docs_new["tech"] = extract_message("C:\\Users\\Cody\\Documents\\Emails\\tech.html")
docs_new["gary"] = extract_message("C:\\Users\\Cody\\Documents\\Emails\\gary.html")
etc.
```

When you iterate over the dictionary, you'll see the keys.

```
for doc, category in zip(docs_new, predicted):
    print('%s ---> %s' % (doc, news.target_names[category]))
```

(More dictionary basics: To iterate over dict values, replace `docs_new` above with `docs_new.values()`; or use `docs_new.items()` for both keys and values.)